# Execute A Function When All xmlHttpRequests Are Complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dom, web-analytics

**BRIEF**

I have a website which gets data from an API. So it makes some post and get requests to a server once the website is opened. Let us assume it makes 5 different **xmlHttpRequests** as soon as the page loads but we cannot exactly know the time each call takes from start to finish.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

Call to one endpoint takes 2 seconds to complete and the other one takes 1 second to complete. So that means after 2 seconds both the calls are said to be **finished**.

**TO-DO**

I want to execute a function after all the **xmlHttpRequests** are **complete** because I am using **window.performance.getEntries()** to fetch all the requests initiated by the webpage and send it to my server as I am doing a web analytics project in which I need to access the times taken by each network request and convert the data into a chart.

**EXTRA-QUESTION OR HINT**

Is there any event that can be attached to the window as shown below to listen for all the network calls and execute my piece of code when all are finished.

```
      window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
       //execute some code here
      }
```

In the load event I am not able to capture all the requests by using **performance.getEntries()** because load fires before the ajax calls are finished.

As shown above I ask. Is there any trick or any event or anything in JavaScript by which we can wait untill all the **XMLHTTPREQUESTS** are finished and then execute some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WORKING SOLUTION**

We can track browser **AJAX** calls using the code below :

```
  const ajaxCallStatus = () => {
   window.ajaxCalls = 0; // initial ajax calls
   window.ajaxEndpoints = []; // keeping track of all ajax call urls (endpoints) 
   const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
   window.ajaxCalls++;
   this.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    if (!window.ajaxEndpoints.includes(event['currentTarget'].responseURL)) {
      window.ajaxEndpoints.push(event['currentTarget'].responseURL);
    }
    window.ajaxCalls--;
    switch (window.ajaxCalls) {
    case 0: // when ajax calls finish this runs
      addData(window.ajaxEndpoints);
    break;
    }
     });
    origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    }
   }
```

**ADD DATA FUNCTION** - Used for sending data to some backend.

```
function addData(arr, origOpen) { 
   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = origOpen;
   axios.post('url', data)
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to wrap your requests in promises and then use `Promise.all(...)` like so:

```
const makeRequest = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                resolve(xhttp.responseText); // On success, resolve the promise
            } else {
                reject(); // On failure, reject it
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true); // Needs to be set to your needs. This is just an example
        xhttp.send();
    });
}

// This waits until all promises are resolved
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all(makeRequest(), makeRequest());

// do stuff here with your results
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

PS: Basic Ajax example is from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), but just swap it for yours and create parameters or similar to make the requests you actually need

OR

You could use a library like Axios for Ajax requests, which already returns Promises by default. Check it out here: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Let us assume I am a web analytics software services provider and I can't tell my user to wrap network calls into a `Promise.all`. Instead I want to provide a script tag which can be added to their html file and loaded automatically in the web page and in that script tag i have got all the event listeners set up. For example DOMContentLoaded etc. So is there any event or way by which we can handle my need ? **The need to listen for all xmlhttp requests completed or not**

Comment: No there is no reliable way to do this, because XMLHttpRequests are by definition asynchronous. You cant wait for the initial load, because there could always be new ones or something like this. If they can be identified somehow, it might be a different story, but just from what you are telling me, it does not sound possible. You might want to check out this: https://medium.com/@gilfink/quick-tip-creating-an-xmlhttprequest-interceptor-1da23cf90b76. Maybe that fits your needs. Scrolls down to the xmlhttp section @basitmir